# Parse JSON record to extract key and value and put into Map in java

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have one column in my table which will store data in string format the sample data is

```
{"pre-date":{"enable":true,"days":"3","interval":"1","mail-template":"582"},"on-date":{"enabled":false},"post-date":{"enabled":false}}
```

and the string contains data like json data
but when i will send this record for controller to view it should be in format

```
enable : true
days : 3
interval : 1
```

so that i can set values to respective form elements how to do this in java any help

Comment: use `GSon` library to parse it, http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) provides the best support for simple conversion of any JSON object into a Java `Map` comprised of only Java SE components.

Following is an example using the JSON from the original question.

```
// {"pre-date":{"enable":true,"days":"3","interval":"1","mail-template":"582"},"on-date":{"enabled":false},"post-date":{"enabled":false}}
String json = "{\"pre-date\":{\"enable\":true,\"days\":\"3\",\"interval\":\"1\",\"mail-template\":\"582\"},\"on-date\":{\"enabled\":false},\"post-date\":{\"enabled\":false}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// To put all of the JSON in a Map<String, Object>
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);

// Accessing the three target data elements
Map<String, Object> preDateMap = (Map) map.get("pre-date");
System.out.println(preDateMap.get("enable"));
System.out.println(preDateMap.get("days"));
System.out.println(preDateMap.get("interval"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the complete JSON string from the database, then parse it using a JSON parser, and extract the information you're interested into from the data structure/object returned from the parsing.

There are lots of JSON parsers available. Look at [this page](http://json.org/), which lists a number of them in the Java section (you have to scroll a little bit down).